# Rails grab input value on submit in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a customer model that belongs to user.  However, when creating the new customer, the user will not be signed in.  Instead I will be assigning the user based on his name attribute.
Here is the customer migration:

```
create_table :customers do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.date :install_date, null: false
  t.decimal :mmr, null: false
  t.boolean :sixty_month, default: false
  t.boolean :eft, default: false
  t.boolean :activation, default: false

  t.timestamps
end
```

I then have a new customer form:

```
<h1>Create Customer</h1>

<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :install_date %>
    <%= f.date_field :install_date %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :mmr %>
    <%= f.number_field :mmr %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :sixty_month %>
    <%= f.check_box :sixty_month %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :eft %>
    <%= f.check_box :eft %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :activation %>
    <%= f.check_box :activation %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :users_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :users_name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Create Customer' %>
<% end %>
```

I need to get the users_name field and match it with the associated user and take that users id and assign it to the customers :user_id attribute.  In the customers controllers create action so far I have:

```
@customer.user_id = User.where("name = #{}").id
```

I need to pull to input from the users_name field in the new customer form and put it into the above code somehow.  I just don't know how haha.  All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to move this out of the controller and into a helper method but you could do like this:

```
    def create
      @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
        if params[:users_name]
          user = User.find_by(name: params[:users_name])
          @customer.user_id = user.id unless user.nil?
        end
       if @customer.save
         flash[:success] = "Customer created!"
         redirect_to @customer
       else
        render 'new'
       end
    end
```

This is assuming you are using Rails 4.

Comment: `Customer.find_by(name: params[:users_name]).id` will raise a \`NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass` if a matching record is not found (tested under rails-4.1.8).

Comment: I think that there is a syntax error up there, an extra parenthesis after the first if line with params

Comment: I ended up also having to change my :users_name field in the create customer form to text_field_tag in place of f.text_field because the customer has no users_name column.